# Are terrain tiles for immurement magic items available?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

Regarding immurements, a class of consumable magic item which transforms a 4×4 square area into a specified sort of terrain, the *Adventurer's Vault 2* says (p. 89):

> Players can find printable maps for the items described in this section on the *D&D™️ Insider* web site at [www.dndinsider.com](http://www.dndinsider.com).

Since the web site is defunct, are the maps for immurements available anywhere else?

Comment: Do you recall if access to the maps required a subscription to D&D Insider?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I don't know whether all of D&D Insider was paywalled or not, no.  The statement "All characters and material will be unavailable starting on January 1, 2020" at https://dnd-support.wizards.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038402091-Goodbye-D-D-Insiders doesn't bode well if it was.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Note that fan created material for this purpose would also be a good answer to this question.

Comment: I've located a couple of immurements in some magazines (Dragon 383 and Dungeon 215), but they aren't the ones located in AV2.  I'm not sure whether/where they were ever published.

Comment: Good news!  I discovered the AV2 immurement JPEGs in my backups.  Any suggestions about what to do with them?